# Detect newer version of Wix bootstrapper

Tags: wix

I have a managed wix bootstrapper and I noticed that I can provide a url for an updated version of the bootstrapper for upgrade detection. However it seems this only runs if my bootstapper has been installed before. Is there any default way for burn to detect a newer version of the bootstrapper before installing the current version? What I would like is if a customer has a copy of a legacy bootstrapper and runs it to install a new machine that the user is provided an option to download the new bootstrapper and run it instead. I assume I could code all this up from scratch in custom bootstrapper but wanted to be sure that I wasn't reinventing the wheel. It seems like there would be given that most of this is already implemented with the update detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing and investigation it looks like I was incorrect about how this works. The detectupdateBegin event does get called even if the bundle hasn't been installed before. You can either allow Wix to consume an atom feed using the app syndication format. If you use this format then the engine will return the latest version in the feed. Otherwise you have to roll your own update service and put the call in the detectupdateBegin event handler. Be sure not to set the result to Ok otherwise the engine will look at your service url and try to process it like an app syndication feed and return an error.

One you detect an update you will need to call Engine.SetUpdate and then call Plan with InstallAction of UpdateReplace.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the reg keys for product version and compare it with your latest.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/update.html, this feature is not available yet and you would have to build it into your custom WPF bootstrapper application.

Comment: This is an undocumented feature. If you look at the Wix source for its own installer you can see this implemented.

Comment: Cool! I added an issue to have the documentation updated: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5237